# Point-in-mesh testing: dealing with problematic cases?

Tags: testing, polygon, point

I need to check to see if a point is inside an arbitrary concave mesh, composed of tris.

I'm using the "shoot ray in an arbitrary direction and check the number of tri intersections...even means point is outside, odd means inside" method to test this.

If the ray always hits the interior of a tri there's no problem. But, if the ray hits either an edge or a vertex, it can cause problems.

For example, imagine 4 tris that all share a common vertex. If the ray passes through that vertex, all 4 tris will report a hit. In that case, even if the starting point is inside the mesh, it will report 4 intersections and consider the point outside the mesh. Similar problems occur when a ray passes through an edge shared by more than one tri.

Are there any good ways of dealing with this problem? My first thought was to simply exclude tris that share verts with other tris which have already been tested...but that would only create more issues.

Answer (score 0):

I guess in that case you can simply collect all hitpoint information in an array and then traverse that array for distinct points and don't count in repeating points and then check the reduced array for even or odd length.